# Set background color of an PDF generated using libHaru

Tags: c++, pdf, pdf-generation, libharu

So I am trying to set background color in C++ using libHaru for my new pdf.

I am having issues setting it. Searched through documentation and either was not there
or I missed it.

Anyone who knows how to set background color for pdf page?

Also any comments on libHaru? Would you recommend it etc would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no background color for a PDF page. If you want to make the page red, for example, you draw a rectangle that covers the page and fill it with red.

Comment: I knew that way of doing it already I was wondering if there was a better way.... add some code and I will accept this as answer. thanks